# Can I find out userid of the remote person logged into windows desktop?

Tags: java, swing, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am running a Java Desktop appplication on one of our windows machine.

And to make any manual changes in our application, one of our **Support persons** remote login from his machine using **mstsc**.  (Let's say "**Tim**")

Here is the catch: For remote connection we use "**MysysUser**" and password for connection.

Now, there is a requirement of logging in who is making the changes. Is there a way of finding out who the remote user is which is not "MysysUser ? It is "Tim".

In my Java code, i want to find out the name **Tim**.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You can't. You should give a specific login to every person that connects if you want to know who they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to get the name of the user logged on the machine of Tim, like this example, this feature use native features from windows.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class UserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        UserName user = new UserName();
        System.out.println(user.getUserLoggedFromIP("localhost"));
        System.out.println(user.getUserLoggedFromIP("IP_MACHINE_OF_TIM"));
    }

    public String getUserLoggedFromIP(String ip) throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("query user /server:" + ip);
        p.waitFor(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));

        String userActive = reader.lines().filter(x -> x.toUpperCase().contains("ACTIVE"))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if(userActive != null){
            return userActive.trim().split(" ")[0];
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i run this command, i get MysysUser as output and not Tim.

Comment: I put two examples, the first line to return the user logged on the machine that you execute this code, second example to put the IP of the machine who Tim use to connect to this machine, Tim need to logged with his user on that machine to this java code return the user logged in other machine. To this code run properly to remote machine, Maybe you need to change this line p.waitFor(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Comment: Also execute this command inside of DOS to understanding the command and see if you can get tim from this list, and if you find Tim, is just need to change the code to parser the Tim position: “query user /server:localhost“